# Is it possible to get the inferred type information using mypy programmatically?

Tags: python, static-analysis, mypy

I'd like to write a program to do static analysis on Python programs. Is it possible to call mypy and get inferred type information programmatically? I expect the input to be a Python program as a string, and the output to be some type-annotated AST or symbol table with type information.

Comment: Did you end up finding any solution?